# Como faço para esconder a barra de rolagem pagina no css?

Tags: css, iframe

```
iframe#frame-spec {
    width:400px;
    height:280px;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
iframe#frame-spec::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta solução, teoricamente abrange todos os navegadores modernos:

```
html {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* ParaFirefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Para Internet Explorer e Edge */
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; /* Para Chrome, Safari, e Opera */
}
```

`html` pode ser substituído por qualquer elemento que você deseja ocultar na barra de rolagem.